# Oric-1 has a digital PAL encoder. Was there any other options for SECAM?

Tags: pal, secam, oric

Although simple, the PAL encoder in Oric-1 was fully digital.

In fact, a 8.8672375 MHz  oscillator (which is 2 times the color carrier frequency in PAL = 2 × 4.43361875 MHz )  along with R,G,B and the Sync signals generated by ULA control the address of the PROM (a 256x4 ) applied to a resistor network making a simple DAC. This signal is then applied to the RF modulator:

[image]

I know that since RGB and Sync are applied to another output port on Oric-1, a SCART(Péritel) could be used in France but since not all TVs were equipped with a SCART this could have limited its market in France.

Since SECAM uses a frequency modulation to code colors, a SECAM digital encoder was impossible to make at the time.

Was there any other options (like integrated analog encoder) for SECAM on some Oric-1 intended for France?

Comment: “not all TVs were equipped with a SCART” — no, in France the vast majority of TVs had SCART (Péritel), in fact it was compulsory on all TVs sold in continental France between 1980 and 2015.

Comment: @StephenKitt are you sure? Oric-1 was launched in 1982 and Péritel was released in France starting from 1980. At the time do you think that people change their TV each two years?

Comment: Good point, my comment wasn’t specific to 1982. However the early 80s in France, at least for families liable to buy a computer (while the Oric 1 was cheap for a computer, it still represented a significant expenditure), were a time of TV upheaval: this was when people started having multiple TVs at home, buying VHS recorders (which used Péritel connections)...

Comment: Such as it may contribute anything, the anecdotal version of events is that the Oric was sold in France only as a consequence of the RGB port making it a good fit for Peritel televisions, after the decision to throw in the RGB port. In that retelling, not much thought was put into the French market and the machine's modest success there was all just a happy piece of luck.

Comment: @Tommy right, and it’s worth bearing in mind that “success” in Europe at the time didn’t require huge sales numbers; the 50,000 Oric 1s sold in France represent a small fraction of the TV market at the time (90% of French homes had a TV by the end of the 70s).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [CPCwiki](https://www.cpcwiki.eu/index.php/Oric_1/Atmos) Oric-1 had something that made it unnecessary to have a SECAM UHF signal. It was (one of few) computers in that price range that had RGB out connector. This made it possible to connect the computer to a TV set through a SCART connector. This connector was widely used in France, although requiring an external power source (remanufactured cables can use/re-route main power source, which saves the need for an extra transformer).